# Synchronization of Multiple Audio Queues

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audioqueue, audioqueueservices

The Audio Queue Documentation from Apple claims to have "Additional advanced features support scheduled playback and synchronization of multiple audio queues". However, no documentation for the same is found anywhere on the net.

I have three Audio Queues, that need synchronous playback/stop/pause/resume.  Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many intriguing looking functions that use `AudioTimeStamp` in the `AudioQueue` header file.

In particular `AudioQueueStart` has an `AudioTimeStamp` parameter called `inStartTime`. 
Maybe you could use the `mHostTime` field to specify the host machine's time base, `mach_absolute_time` which you ought to be able to use to synchronise multiple audio queues.

Then I guess you'd use the `inStartTime` argument in `AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters` to queue your buffers at the right time. Not sure how you'd synchronise stop...

Personally, I've found `AudioQueues` to generate more heartache than LPCM, so I'd mix and output the three audio streams myself using a remote io audio unit (or the modern equivalent) because you get synchronised play,resume/stop,pause for free.

Comment: Actually, I am getting audio buffers from the socket connection continuously. So here I am facing problem to sync with Video. Any leads would save my day?

Comment: Make sure to have only one timeline (probably hosttime) and map audio and video to that. And ask a new question detailing what apis you're using.

Comment: using AudioQueueServices APIs.